# ListView: fetching details with FutureBuilder results in glitchy behavior

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have a ListView and I am using ListView.builder to lazily populate the list when children get visible.

However, the items also need to render additional content which I want to fetch lazily.

To do that, I am constructing an http-get-future in the child-builder and pass it to a FutureBuilder that renders the additional content as soon as the Future completes.

However, even if I cache the http-get-futures, the whole list feels glitchy since the items are rebuild when they get visible again and the FutureBuilder renders always one waiting-frame without any data (“because there is no way to synchronously check if a Future already completed” — as the Flutter docs say).

What should I change?

Comment: use `MapCache` - it internally keeps a map of outstanding calls used to prevent concurrent loads of the same key.

Comment: The problem is the initial frame in which the FuturBuilder has no data. Don’t think that a MapCache helps here because I do already cache the Futures.

Comment: well if you have no initial data then show some `CircularProgressIndicator` or something

Comment: The glitch happens the second time the list item is visible. I already then have the data wrapped in a Future in my cache, but FutureBuilder still draws one frame without the data. That results in a short flicker.

Comment: you have several concurrent `Futures` (each one for loading one or more items), right? so what `Future` is passed to `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: Each item in the ListView has ONE Future to load details of that item. So each item in the ListView is wrapped in a FutureBuilder with getting the corresponding Future from the cache. However, the FutureBuilder ALWAYS builds one frame without any data even though the Future already has completed previously.

Comment: so use one `StatefulWidget` instead of multiple `FutureBuilder`s where you will have more control over your `Future`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Instead of directly using a Future in the FutureBuilder, I put a ValueNotifier in the cache that is set inside of the Future‘s then function and a replace the FutureBuilder by a ListenableBuilder.

The ListenableBuilder does not have the issue with the empty frame...

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved by using "reverse: true"

ListView.builder(
reverse: true,
...
)[image]